# Subscribing to answers

Tags: support

I have a question about my Server Fault post: [finding cause for kernel-power error 41 (scenario 3)](https://serverfault.com/questions/901717/finding-cause-for-kernel-power-error-41-scenario-3)

Generally, how can I get notified when someone answers my question?  I don't want to keep checking the question page all the time.  Can I get an email when an answer is received?

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you can do that in your [user profile](https://serverfault.com/users/email/settings/460730).